# Android: Checkbox avoid list item be selected

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, selector, android-relativelayout

I have a `ListView` with a custom list item layout and a selection  state for that layout, also i have a `checkbox` inside a item layout, the problem is,the checkbox  is avoiding list item be `selected` when is presented in layout, but when i change the visibility to `gone` of `checkbox` the layout for item respond to `selectors`.

**selector_list.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CustomTextView
            android:id="@id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_8"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_light_d2"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_12"
            custom:typeface="robotoBold" />

        <CheckBox                
            android:id="@android:id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add these attributes to check box and try   `android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below attributes to the check box

```
 android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

or add the below to the relative layout an try.

```
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

This happens because the checkbox takes focus when you click on the list item. So try the above suggestions